# Date diff across Date frame

Tags: r

I need to figure our how many visitors never came after 2 days. This analyze regarding to first time visitors. I have 6 months time period since Jul-Dec and anybody who has Visit Number = 1 somewhere in that time period is considered as first time visitor.

Let say I have the following simple data frame:

```
a <- data.frame("Date"=c("July 1, 2016","July 1, 2016","July 1, 2016","July 2, 2016","July 2, 2016","July 3, 2016","July 3, 2016","July 3, 2016",
                     "July 4, 2016","July 5, 2016","July 6, 2016"),
            "UserID"=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
            "Visit No"=c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 6, 7, 20))
```

How can I figure out how many first time visitors never came after 2 days?

In my simple example the first time visitor who never came after 2 days seems to be UserID 1, because he never came after two days since July 2, 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


dt <- data.frame("Date"=c("July 1, 2016","July 1, 2016","July 1, 2016","July 2, 2016","July 2, 2016","July 3, 2016","July 3, 2016","July 3, 2016",
                         "July 4, 2016","July 5, 2016","July 6, 2016"),
                "UserID"=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                "Visit No"=c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 6, 7, 20))

dt %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>%     # update to date format
  group_by(UserID) %>%             # for each user id
  mutate(Date_Next = lead(Date, default=max(mdy(dt$Date))),    # get date of next visit. if there's no next visit consider the latest date in the dataset
         Date_Diff = as.numeric(difftime(Date_Next, Date, units="days"))) %>%    # calculate difference between dates
  ungroup() %>%                    # forget the grouping
  filter(Date_Diff > 2)            # return cases where difference is more than 2 days

# # A tibble: 1 × 5
#           Date UserID Visit.No  Date_Next Date_Diff
#          <date>  <dbl>    <dbl>     <date>     <dbl>
#   1 2016-07-02      1        1 2016-07-06         4
```

The process will return CASES where users don't return after 2 days and not USERS. You'll probably need to get unique user ids from this output, in case a user repeatedly returns after 3+ days.

Comment: If you can create some "extreme" examples we can easily modify the code to get the output you like.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)

a <- data.frame("Date"=c("July 1, 2016","July 1, 2016","July 1, 2016","July 2, 2016","July 2, 2016","July 3, 2016","July 3, 2016","July 3, 2016",
                                    "July 4, 2016","July 5, 2016","July 6, 2016"),
                                 "UserID"=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                                 "Visit No"=c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 6, 7, 20))

a$ParsedDate <- strptime(a$Date,"%B %d, %Y",tz = "UTC")

**creating the variable with unique UserIDs to run the loop**

d <- unique(a$UserID)

for(i in 1:length(d))
{
 #DF per UserID
 adfPerUser <-  a[a$UserID == d[i],]

 #now create the interval variable
 intervallistvar <- as.interval(min(adfPerUser$ParsedDate) + 2*24*60*60, max(adfPerUser$ParsedDate))

 #DF for the UserID[i] for the two days
 adfPerUser2days <- adfPerUser[adfPerUser$ParsedDate %within% intervallistvar,]

 if(nrow(adfPerUser2days) >= 1)
 {
   cat(sprintf("User ID = %d and has visited atleast once after two days from the first time visit\n", i))
 }
}
```

See the output now:

[image: output]